Creating reports from a Google Sheets
I´ve given the task to create a script that creates a document file as a report based on a spreadsheet. Now I´ve tried several types of aproach but none of these aproaches created the document in question.
[This is the base spreadsheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uKhuy0FBwn2w-wVcLer0aeKRxhbvX7GkBqdDKnbc_qM/edit?usp=sharing)
the code I have until now is this
function criarRelatoriosCentro() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var unidades = {};
  var data = new Date();
  var meses = ["janeiro", "fevereiro", "março", "abril", "maio", "junho", "julho", "agosto", "setembro", "outubro", "novembro", "dezembro"];
  var hoje = data.getDate() + '-' + meses[data.getMonth()] + '-' + data.getFullYear();
  
  // Obtém os dados da planilha
  var range = ss.getSheetByName("Centro").getDataRange();
  var valores = range.getValues();
  
  // Preenche o objeto 'unidades' com os dados da planilha
  for (var i = 1; i < valores.length; i++) {
    var ativo = valores[i][0];
    var unidade = valores[i][1];
    var equipe = valores[i][2];
    var dados = valores[i].slice(4, 70); // Dados da coluna E até BO
    
    if (ativo === true && unidade && equipe) { // Verifica se a unidade está marcada como TRUE
      if (!unidades[unidade]) {
        unidades[unidade] = {
          nome: unidade,
          equipes: [],
          dados: {}
        };
      }
      
      unidades[unidade].equipes.push(equipe);
      
      // Cria um objeto para cada coluna entre E e BO
      for (var j = 0; j < dados.length; j++) {
        var coluna = String.fromCharCode(69 + j); // 69 é o código ASCII para 'E'
        unidades[unidade].dados[coluna] = dados[j];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Cria os relatórios para cada unidade
  for (var unidade in unidades) {
    var nomeDocumento = "Relatório CS " + unidades[unidade].nome + " " + hoje;
    var doc = DocumentApp.create(nomeDocumento);

    // Verifica se o documento foi criado com sucesso
    if (!doc) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Falha ao criar o documento: " + nomeDocumento);
      continue; // Pula para a próxima iteração do loop
    }


    var body = doc.getBody();

    var colunaE = unidades[unidade].dados['E']; // Acessa o valor da coluna E
    var colunaF = unidades[unidade].dados['F'];
    var colunaG = unidades[unidade].dados['G'];
    var colunaH = unidades[unidade].dados['H'];
    var colunaI = unidades[unidade].dados['I'];
    var colunaJ = unidades[unidade].dados['J'];
    var colunaK = unidades[unidade].dados['K'];
    var colunaL = unidades[unidade].dados['L'];
    var colunaM = unidades[unidade].dados['M'];
    var colunaN = unidades[unidade].dados['N'];
    var colunaO = unidades[unidade].dados['O'];
    var colunaP = unidades[unidade].dados['P'];
    var colunaQ = unidades[unidade].dados['Q'];
    var colunaR = unidades[unidade].dados['R'];
    var colunaS = unidades[unidade].dados['S'];
    var colunaT = unidades[unidade].dados['T'];
    var colunaU = unidades[unidade].dados['U'];
    var colunaV = unidades[unidade].dados['V'];
    var colunaW = unidades[unidade].dados['W'];
    var colunaX = unidades[unidade].dados['X'];
    var colunaY = unidades[unidade].dados['Y'];
    var colunaZ = unidades[unidade].dados['Z'];
    var colunaAA = unidades[unidade].dados['AA'];
    var colunaAB = unidades[unidade].dados['AB'];
    var colunaAC = unidades[unidade].dados['AC'];
    var colunaAD = unidades[unidade].dados['AD'];
    var colunaAE = unidades[unidade].dados['AE'];
    var colunaAF = unidades[unidade].dados['AF'];
    var colunaAG = unidades[unidade].dados['AG'];
    var colunaAH = unidades[unidade].dados['AH'];
    var colunaAI = unidades[unidade].dados['AI'];
    var colunaAJ = unidades[unidade].dados['AJ'];
    var colunaAK = unidades[unidade].dados['AK'];
    var colunaAL = unidades[unidade].dados['AL'];
    var colunaAM = unidades[unidade].dados['AM'];
    var colunaAN = unidades[unidade].dados['AN'];
    var colunaAO = unidades[unidade].dados['AO'];
    var colunaAP = unidades[unidade].dados['AP'];
    var colunaAQ = unidades[unidade].dados['AQ'];
    var colunaAR = unidades[unidade].dados['AR'];
    var colunaAS = unidades[unidade].dados['AS'];
    var colunaAT = unidades[unidade].dados['AT'];
    var colunaAU = unidades[unidade].dados['AU'];
    var colunaAV = unidades[unidade].dados['AV'];
    var colunaAW = unidades[unidade].dados['AW'];
    var colunaAX = unidades[unidade].dados['AX'];
    var colunaAY = unidades[unidade].dados['AY'];
    var colunaAZ = unidades[unidade].dados['AZ'];
    var colunaBA = unidades[unidade].dados['BA'];
    var colunaBB = unidades[unidade].dados['BB'];
    var colunaBC = unidades[unidade].dados['BC'];
    var colunaBD = unidades[unidade].dados['BD'];
    var colunaBE = unidades[unidade].dados['BE'];
    var colunaBF = unidades[unidade].dados['BF'];
    var colunaBG = unidades[unidade].dados['BG'];
    var colunaBH = unidades[unidade].dados['BH'];
    var colunaBI = unidades[unidade].dados['BI'];
    var colunaBJ = unidades[unidade].dados['BJ'];
    var colunaBK = unidades[unidade].dados['BK'];
    var colunaBL = unidades[unidade].dados['BL'];
    var colunaBM = unidades[unidade].dados['BM'];
    var colunaBN = unidades[unidade].dados['BN'];
    var colunaBO = unidades[unidade].dados['BO'];
    var colunaBP = unidades[unidade].dados['BP'];
    var colunaBQ = unidades[unidade].dados['BQ'];
    var colunaBR = unidades[unidade].dados['BR'];
    var colunaBS = unidades[unidade].dados['BS'];
    var colunaBT = unidades[unidade].dados['BT'];
    var colunaBU = unidades[unidade].dados['BU'];
    var colunaBV = unidades[unidade].dados['BV'];
    var colunaBW = unidades[unidade].dados['BW'];
    var colunaBX = unidades[unidade].dados['BX'];
    var colunaBY = unidades[unidade].dados['BY'];
    var colunaBZ = unidades[unidade].dados['BZ'];
    var textoPredeterminado = "Este é o texto pré-determinado que será inserido em cada relatório. Aqui estão os dados específicos: " + colunaE + ", " + colunaF + ", " + colunaG + ", " + colunaH + ", ..., " + colunaBO;
    
    
    body.appendParagraph("Relatório para a unidade: " + unidades[unidade].nome);
    body.appendParagraph("Equipes ativas:");
    body.appendParagraph(unidades[unidade].equipes.join(", "));
    body.appendParagraph("Dados:");
    body.appendParagraph(unidades[unidade].dados.join(", "));
    body.appendParagraph(textoPredeterminado);
    
    // Salva o ID do documento na planilha
    ss.getSheetByName("Centro").getRange("BM" + (Number(i) + 1)).setValue(doc.getId());

    // Exibe um alerta com o ID do documento
    var docId = doc.getId();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Relatório criado com sucesso! O ID do documento é: " + docId);

    // Move o documento para uma pasta específica
    var pastaId = 'https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MK8KRyFJoYiuD7Ue4GYupJGT7jB06a3K'; // Substitua 'ID_DA_SUA_PASTA' pelo ID da sua pasta
    var arquivo = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    DriveApp.getFolderById(pastaId).addFile(arquivo);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(arquivo);
  }
  
 
}

function onOpen() {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Relatórios');
  menu.addItem('Criar Relatório Centro','criarRelatoriosCentro').addToUi();
  menu.addItem('Criar Relatório Continente','criarRelatoriosContinente').addToUi();
  menu.addItem('Criar Relatório Norte','criarRelatoriosNorte').addToUi();
  menu.addItem('Criar Relatório Sul','criarRelatoriosSul').addToUi();
}

I Tried to create the document in the same page but no results
to put a warning if the document wasn´t created but the warning did not appear, and put a UI alert after document creation with the link to the new document but no good on creating the document neither on showing the alert.
The script should consider Column A if true to start the new document using the pattern "relatorio +  + Date of creation"
Column B has nested informations thru all the spreadsheet, column C specifies  for which workgroup the information belongs to. This is one question I did´nt see how it gets because I just cant Get the damn report document

ESF/ESB number are workgroups ID´s that work inside the "CENTRO SAÚDE"

I couldn´t save the document file with any other type of saving. looking at google sheets comunity they come of something like that then I admit I got fed up of this damn spreadsheet and code so i ChatGPT the solution and thats what chat GPT comes as response.
ESF/ESB number are workgroups ID´s that work inside the "CENTRO SAÚDE"
I was just trying every hipotesis I had this is the cleanest and nearer to work code that I´ve done. this is the 6th or 7th code version.
And like I said on my profile I know little almost nothing of javascritpt I know more of python but google dont use it.


I do not need the document ID created and stored on my spreadsheet.  I just need to create a document file to be created at the same folder or in a predetermined folder.

2 - Yes i need ColA to be checked and ColB populated but I need the Col C to be accounted It May have to index some some of the data.
3 - I will make a Doc Sample to show what is needed
thanks for your time.

Hope this sample is enough to exemplify:
link

That is helpful.  Please add a version that includes the actual data from your sample spreadsheet. Complete the report for both "Agronômica" and "Centro".  I don't want any confusion on my part.  Ty!

Okay, I've got some working code. I'm stopping pending an example of a report for Agronômica using the actual data from your sheet (per my previous comment).  Once you post that I'll wrap it up.

I can't realistically move forward without a sample see image
